# loading saved model doesn't behave as expected when finetuning it

Tags: python, model, pytorch, fine-tuning

I trained a `pytorch` model the accuracy at end of the first epoch is 20% and the loss value is 3.8 . I trained it until the loss is 3.2 and accuracy is around 50% and save it like this:

```
 torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.pth')
```

Then I load it like this:

```
model = Perceptron(input_size, output_size)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth"))
model.to(device, dtype=torch.double)
```

When I'm starting to fine-tune it using the same task, same optimizer, and learning rate, I expect the loss starts at 3.2 and accuracy to be 50% but it looks like the model is rolling back and starts from a loss value of 3.8 and accuracy of 20% again. Is something wrong with my code or there's something that I don't understand about the fine-tuning model?

Answer (score 0):

First, because you need to fine-tune, the optimizer also needs to be saved:

```py
state = {'model': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
torch.save(state, "model.pth")
```

And then:

```py
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth")['model])
optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth")['optimizer'])
```

Second, you need to set the random seed at the very beginning of the code

```py
def setup_seed(seed):
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

setup_seed(20)
```